# Reschedule IntentService with AlarmManager - intent extra info is ignored

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

I have an IntentService that is initially started with the click on a button:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProximityService.class);
        intent.putExtra("com.hybris.proxi.triggerTime", 5000l);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,  0,  intent, 0);
        long trigger = System.currentTimeMillis() + (5*1000);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger, pendingIntent);
```

This works nicely. But then I am trying to execute the same intentservice again, from within the intentservice. The idea here is that I can vary the next execution time to save battery.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("demo", "ProximityService... STARTING");
    Log.d("demo", "Intent has extra with key com.hybris.proxi.triggerTime" + intent.hasExtra("com.hybris.proxi.triggerTime"));

    long lastTriggerTime = intent.getLongExtra("com.hybris.proxi.triggerTime", -1);
    Log.d("demo", "Last trigger time: " + lastTriggerTime);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //trigger me again - TODO change this based on closeness to store
    //TODO does not work, somehow triggertime is not incremented
    if (lastTriggerTime < 50000)
    {
        long newTriggerTime = lastTriggerTime * 2;

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ProximityService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("com.hybris.proxi.triggerTime", (long)newTriggerTime);
        Log.d("demo","New triggerTime set in new intent is : " + serviceIntent.getLongExtra("com.hybris.proxi.triggerTime", -1));

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,  0,  serviceIntent, 0);
        long trigger = System.currentTimeMillis() + newTriggerTime;
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger, pendingIntent);
        Log.d("demo", "Alarm was set with trigger time " + newTriggerTime);
    } 
    else {
        Log.d("demo", "Not rescheduling alarm: lastTriggerTime is " + lastTriggerTime);
    }


    Log.d("demo", "ProximityService... DONE");

}
```

The problem is that

intent.getLongExtra("com.hybris.proxi.triggerTime", -1);

always returns the initial value 5000 - so the next alarm is not scheduled at an inceasing trigger time. Somehow, the setting of the intent extra for the new trigger time does not work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, using `getService()` with a `_WAKEUP` alarm will be unreliable. The only guarantee with `_WAKEUP` alarms is that *if* you use a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent`, *then* the device will stay awake long enough for `onReceive()` to do its work. In all other cases, the device may fall asleep before you get control.

Comment: Does this mean I should register a broadcast receiver that then triggers the intent service? And the intent service woudl finally create a new alarm for the broad cast receiver again I guess. But then I believe I need to create a wake lock for the intent service, or is this happening automatically?

Comment: Yes, that is one approach. You will also need a `WakeLock` of your own to keep the device awake for your `IntentService` to start up and do the work. I have a `WakefulIntentService` that wraps up this pattern: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Comment: thx, this is great input. I just looked at the WakefulIntentService. One thing I do not understand is why the BroadcastReceiver (AlarmReceiver) not simply starts the intentService - why does it call  listener.sendWakefulWork(ctxt); for example. Could I not simply call startService() and then acquire the wake lock in the onHandleIntent method? I don't expect my intent service executions to overlap btw - I just want to call the service each few minutes.

Comment: "why does it call listener.sendWakefulWork(ctxt); for example" -- because we have to acquire a `WakeLock`. " Could I not simply call startService() and then acquire the wake lock in the onHandleIntent method?" -- no, because `startService()` is asynchronous, and the device can therefore fall asleep before `onHandleIntent()` is called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to Use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Change your code from 
`PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,  0,  serviceIntent, 0);` 
 to

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
                        0,  serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```